# View Object for Dropdown selection

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm looking to create a UI in swift with Xcode, but I can't find the correct object for it. I have an array of elements (think tableView). I want to select a subset of these elements. When the object is not clicked on (Dropped down) I want it to display a list of the selected elements. Any ideas what to use?

**waiting**

```
[ELEMENT A]
[ELEMENT D]
```

**selected**

```
[ELEMENT A*]
[ELEMENT B]
[ELEMENT C]
[ELEMENT D*]
[ELEMENT E]
```

thanks

Comment: Thinking with tableview : you might want to create one with a header for each section, then when you tap on the header you can (un)collapse the rows below.

Comment: you need to find by accordion menu, there are a lot in Swift using `UITableView`, I made myself one for a project I need , you can see it here https://github.com/Vkt0r/AccordionMenu